# how to compare null and non null values in single statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying fetch rows when a certain where condition satisfies

```
select * from users where userid = :userid and objnum = :objnum;
```

users table has userid(non nullable column) and objnum(nullable column).
Now when I want to fetch users with null **"objnum"** values,it does not work since null values are not comparable.And when I want to fetch objnum value = 1,then above will work.

For null value, I very well get results with below query.

```
select * from users where userid = :userid and objnum is null;
```

But my application code is sending the :objnum bind variable as **null or integer values** and I want to check it directly in single query.Is there a way out to do this in a single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare a column value to a bind variable and have them match for both `NULL` and non-`NULL` values then for the `NULL` values you need to compare both sides to `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  (userid = :userid OR (userid IS NULL AND :userid IS NULL))
AND    (objnum = :objnum OR (objnum IS NULL AND :objnum IS NULL));
```

Comment: Although I dont need userId since it wont be null in any case.It works like a charm for objnum.Thanks @MT0